# Excel how to transfer data from one sheet to another sheets

Tags: excel

I face with problem in **Excel**. The problem is I have a **3** sheets I need to transfer from one sheet to another sheets data.

> For Example: I have a data in colums A B C D and E. In column **E** I have digits positive or negatives and I need to transfer data in columns A B C D to near and far sheets if in column **E** number is position transfer A B C D data to near Sheet else to far sheet.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPx5m.png)

How to do it. Does anyone know it? please help me!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: To transfer data you need VBA coding. You can use FILTER() function to appear data to near and far sheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr without VBA. I can use filter and if it will be work no?

Comment: Filter() will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive values use-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!E:E>0)
```

For negative values use-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!E:E<0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working but I have another question what if It's not number if It's string like this -1 -2 -3 and +0 +1 +2 +3 in this case how to solve this

Comment: @Laziz Are they text then? Can you put a screenshot of your data sheet?

Comment: I added but its in russian I use the index and match functions @Harun24hr

Comment: You may try something like `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,--(Sheet1!BJ:BJ)>=0)` and `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,--(Sheet1!BJ:BJ)<0)`

Comment: and what if I want to take column A, C and D in this case will work filter or need to use VBA

Comment: Can you check you have access to `CHOOSECOLS()` function. If it then could use it.

Comment: Big THANKS BROTHER I LOVE YOU THANKS